# How can I make a child follow the same behaviour as its parent when using opacity and visibility properties on both of them?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the probably unclear title, but I don't know how to accurately describe the problem I am facing. I've create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grj8x56c/2/) to hopefully clarify the problem.

I have the following layout in which all 4 divs have `opacity: 1` and `visibility: visible` and div **a** and **b** both have `position:absolute` with `top: 0` and `left: 0`.

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="child-a"></div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <div class="child-b"></div>
</div>
```

If you look at the example you can change div **b** to: `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden` (this happens with a transition). Now you only see div **a** and its child **child-a**. You CAN click on div **a** but you cannot click on **child-a**. If you try to do so, you will actually have clicked on **child-b**.

It appears eventhough **child-b**'s parent does not get triggered by mouseevents anymore and seems to be hidden, the child still listens for/ gets triggered by them. I would expect the child to also be "truly" hidden like its parent.

How can I make sure the click on the area where you *see* **child-a** actually is applied on**child-a** as well? I do want to be able to use a transitions in opacity between showing and hiding the div, so using `display:none` is something you cannot transition (as far as I understand it).

I did add the `display:none` toggle in the example because that toggle does behave the way I whould expect (only then you cannot transition anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play a bit with `pointer-events`:

```
.fade-in {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.fade-in.show-me {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.fade-in .fade-in {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.show-me .show-me {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("c")[0];
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0];
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("e")[0];
var childA = document.getElementsByClassName("child-a")[0];
var childB = document.getElementsByClassName("child-b")[0];

c.onclick = function () {
  if (b.classList.contains("show-me")) {
    b.classList.remove("show-me");
  } else {
    b.classList.add("show-me");
  }
};
d.onclick = function () {
  if (b.classList.contains("hide")) {
    b.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    b.classList.add("hide");
  }
};

a.onclick = function () { console.log("a");e.innerHTML = "a<br>"+e.innerHTML; };
b.onclick = function () { console.log("b");e.innerHTML = "b<br>"+e.innerHTML; };
childA.onclick = function (ev) {ev.stopPropagation(); console.log("child-a");e.innerHTML = "child-a<br>"+e.innerHTML; };
childB.onclick = function (ev) {ev.stopPropagation(); console.log("child-b");e.innerHTML = "child-b<br>"+e.innerHTML; };
```

```css
.a,
.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.a:hover,.b:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
}
.a {
  background-color: #fee;
}
.b {
  background-color: #eef;
}
.child-a,.child-b {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.child-a:hover,.child-b:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}
.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.fade-in.show-me {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.fade-in .fade-in {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.show-me .show-me {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.c, .d {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.c:hover, .d:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000; 
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.e {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="a fade-in show-me">
  <div class="child-a fade-in show-me">a-child</div>
</div>
<div class="b fade-in show-me">
  <div class="child-b fade-in show-me">b-child</div>
</div>

<div class="c">Toggle b opacity and visibility</div>
<div class="d">Toggle b display</div>
<div class="e"></div>
```

Comment: haha nice, I am trying to apply this now in my project. The example I made in fiddle is a bit less complicated than my actual code but the idea behind it still applies. Thx ill get back to you soon!

Comment: If the complete code is more complex give more information/demo so I'll be able to take a look.

Comment: Thanks Dekel! This is works, however it is a bit hard to implement in my current project. Do you feel like there is another css way as wel? Or will javascript be needed?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's hard to implement in your current project.. I'm sure you only need to understand the concept and to see which elements are the wrappers and which are the childs, and set the correct `pointer-events`.

Comment: Yes the concept is clear and will work. However in my project classes extend the fade-in class. So to map it back to the example I provided .a,.b, .fade-in {...} instead of using the fade-in class on the div. Now you can only use the "a" class. the name in this case is also used for some other purposes and changing the name would cause some problems. But no worries! I'm going to change that instead ;) Thx!

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127233/discussion-between-dex-and-dekel).

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure how this can be achieved with pure css alone, you can use the javascript to achieve what you are looking for.

`Visibility: hidden` only hides the container, but the element exists on the page whereas `display: none` removes the element from the page. So when the visibility is hidden, the clicks will still handled by the topmost layer i.e the the child-b or the parent b, depending of where you click.

All you need to do is to hide the element like to are doing currently and then also add a setTimeout function that will set the display of the parent b to none after a delay equal to the transition period.

Here's the code

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("c")[0];
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0];
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("e")[0];
var childA = document.getElementsByClassName("child-a")[0];
var childB = document.getElementsByClassName("child-b")[0];

c.onclick = function() {
  if (b.classList.contains("show-me")) {
    b.classList.remove("show-me");

    // delay it for the same period as the transition, 200ms in this case
    setTimeout(function() {
      b.style.display = "none";
    }, 200);

  } else {
    b.style.display = "block";
    b.classList.add("show-me");

  }
};
d.onclick = function() {
  if (b.classList.contains("hide")) {
    b.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    b.classList.add("hide");
  }
};

a.onclick = function() {
  console.log("a");
  e.innerHTML = "a<br>" + e.innerHTML;
};
b.onclick = function() {
  console.log("b");
  e.innerHTML = "b<br>" + e.innerHTML;
};
childA.onclick = function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  console.log("child-a");
  e.innerHTML = "child-a<br>" + e.innerHTML;
};
childB.onclick = function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  console.log("child-b");
  e.innerHTML = "child-b<br>" + e.innerHTML;
};
```

```css
.a,
.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.a:hover,
.b:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
}
.a {
  background-color: #fee;
}
.b {
  background-color: #eef;
}
.child-a,
.child-b {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.child-a:hover,
.child-b:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}
.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.fade-in.show-me {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.c,
.d {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.c:hover,
.d:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.e {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="a fade-in show-me">
  <div class="child-a fade-in show-me">a-child</div>
</div>
<div class="b fade-in show-me">
  <div class="child-b fade-in show-me">b-child</div>
</div>

<div class="c">Toggle b opacity and visibility</div>
<div class="d">Toggle b display</div>
<div class="e"></div>
```

Comment: Yes I though of this type of solution as well only then you always have to take the delay into consideration. I am trying @Dekel' s version now and see if it works :) Thanks for you awnser though! =)

Comment: Yes, pointer events seem like the way to go. I learnt something new and useful today. Cheers